# Did Marketing Cloud remove the ability to create Commercial Triggered Sends via Api?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, triggered-send

I seem to be unable to create Triggered Sends with any Send Classifications that are not transactional.  This is thru both the Rest and SOAP Apis.  Previously, I could create these definitions thru the SOAP Api without any issue, and I still am able to create them in certain Accounts via SOAP (but not Rest).

Example SOAP Envelope that Works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{subdomain}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>      
      <fueloauth>{token}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <CustomerKey>Test-SOAP</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Test-SOAP</Name>
                <SendClassification>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <CustomerKey>Default Transactional</CustomerKey>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                </SendClassification>
                <Email>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <CustomerKey>{Key}</CustomerKey>
                </Email>
                <List>
                    <CustomerKey>{Key}</CustomerKey>
                </List>
                <SendSourceDataExtension>
                    <CustomerKey>{key}</CustomerKey>
                </SendSourceDataExtension>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Example that Fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <s:Header>
          <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
          <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{subdomain}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>      
          <fueloauth>{token}</fueloauth>
       </s:Header>
        <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <CustomerKey>Test-SOAP</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>Test-SOAP</Name>
                    <SendClassification>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <CustomerKey>Default Commercial</CustomerKey>
                        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </SendClassification>
                    <Email>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <CustomerKey>{Key}</CustomerKey>
                    </Email>
                    <List>
                        <CustomerKey>{Key}</CustomerKey>
                    </List>
                    <SendSourceDataExtension>
                        <CustomerKey>{key}</CustomerKey>
                    </SendSourceDataExtension>
                </Objects>
            </CreateRequest>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Failure Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>UpdateResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:4c86b1d4-797d-444a-a118-39410d1c61b4</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:fa19f81b-d6dd-4ca9-b028-15e3739f8d25</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-b09262cf-e876-400d-907e-d6db3afed2c7">
                <wsu:Created>2021-10-07T16:52:16Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2021-10-07T16:57:16Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <UpdateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Results>
                <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
                <StatusMessage>Exception occurred during [UpdateTriggeredSendDefinition] ErrorID = 1686049139</StatusMessage>
                <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
                <ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode>
                <Object xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
                    ...
                </Object>
            </Results>
            <RequestID>5688e823-7684-4a27-9ab6-aacb40642c99</RequestID>
            <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
        </UpdateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Example REST payload:

```
{        
    "name": "TEST_EMAIL_Commercial_Trigger",
    "definitionKey": "TEST_EMAIL_Commercial_Trigger",        
    "description": "TEST_EMAIL_Commercial_Trigger Def",
    "classification": "Default Commercial"
    "content": {
        "customerKey": "{key}"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "dataExtension": "{key}",
        "list": "{key}",
        "autoAddSubscriber": true,
        "updateSubscriber": true
    },
    "options": {
        "trackLinks": true
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "message": "MCMS_UTM_Validation_InvalidValue_classification: Send Classification Default Commercial does not exist in this account or is not Transactional.",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

When did this change?  I still have Triggered Sends with Commercial send classifications that were created via Api and are in use for sending email via Api running OK in a couple Marketing Cloud accounts (both enterprise and non-enterprise accounts).  Is there any way around this (seemingly new?) limitation - ie create Commercial Triggered Send - or is there another approach I should look into for sending triggered, Commercial emails via Api?

Comment: there is no change regarding this, are you able to create the same configuration within the UI?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the sender profile configured in the send classification.